# Facebook web app login works with ip but not with domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

So I am using FB login in this website ***xyz.com*** which has ip address ***x.x.x.x***

When i use the ip address ***x.x.x.x:8000*** in the FB settings and then open this same ip in the browser, the login works fine.
But when i replace the ip with the domain ***xyz.com:8000*** in FB settings and then open the link ***xyz.com:8000*** it gives the error

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Doesn't seems to be possible. Can you share the link?

Comment: I cant see any facebook login button.

Comment: the port is 8000. try 54.251.117.200:8000 or karmabite.com:8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the both examples: **xyz.com** and **x.x.x.x** you've used the same App ID: `14*****80`; that's the problem.

There should be two different apps (and app ids of course) for different site urls; eg:

> xyz.com  - APP_ID_1
>   
>   x.x.x.x - APP_ID_2

You said that you replace the ip with the domain xyz.com:8000 in FB settings, that's **not** possible! Since the login is working fine on x.x.x.x. So please check this again!

Another problem could be the port no, so try removing the domain field from the app settings, if you have set any.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I thought facebook treats domain and ip as the same and i can use them interchangeably. Guess i was wrong.

Comment: No wait. That didn't help. I created a new FB app with settings URL karmabite.com:8000 ... And still the same error.
PS: since the url is being forwarded to the ip, there's only one version of my web-application which is accessible by both, ip and domain.

Comment: But I'm now able to login successfully with your site. Refresh the page properly/ clear cache and try

Comment: ohkay. may be the caching problem. if works with you then must be fine :) thanks a lottt :)